# Как сделать переход на другую страницу при нажатию на кнопку формы в Django

Tags: python, django

Имеется форма. Я написал представление, где по нажатия на кнопку "создать статью" выводится  форма. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы после того как пользователь нажмет на кнопу опубликовать, у него делался переход на страницу где все статьи.

Answer (score 2):

Для этого вы можете использовать в вашем представлении функцию `redirect`

Пример использования:

```
# Ваш views.py
from django.views.generic import View
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class AddArticle(View):
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Ваш код
        return redirect('blog')
```

Где `blog` в urls.py:

```
# urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import Blog

urlpatterns = [
    # ***
    path('', Blog.as_view(), name='blog'),
]
```

Answer (score -1):

В файле html дописать c ссылкой на {% url 'blog' %}, где 'blog' - страница где все статьи.

```html
<a href="{% url 'blog' %}"><button>Создать статью</button></a>
```

Comment: да, работает, но не решает проблему. как минимум в итоге должна быть создана статья, а не переход на создание статьи